# temperary shared parallelism (OMP) within distributed environment (MPI)

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, mpi, openmp

Consider the following scenario:

1. We use `n` MPI processes to evaluate chunks of a large matrix `A`. Each chunk is evaluated by a unique process. Number of OMP threads is `1`.
2. We gather these chunks in the master process (rank=0) and build the full matrix `A`.
3. The master process calls a function `x = f(A)` and broadcasts the result `x` to all processes.

The issue is that `f(A)` takes a long time, and other processes have to wait.
If the function `f` can be accelerated with OMP parallelism, does it make sense to set the number of OMP threads (on the master process) equal to `n` before calling `f(A)` and changing it to `1` afterwards?
In other words, what can be wrong with the following pseudo-code?

```sh
mpirun -n n ./exe    # command for running the code
```

where the pseudo-code for `exe` looks something like

```
a = g(mpi_rank, ... )          # process-specific matrix

A = mpi_gather(a, mpi_rank=0)  # gather all 

if mpi_rank == 0
    set_num_omp_threads(n)
    x = f(A)
    set_num_omp_threads(1)
else
    x = 0

mpi_bcast(x, mpi_rank=0)
```

what are the possible performance issues/pitfalls?

EDIT: The original code is too complicated, but I have replicated the issue via the following code.

```py
# run by: mpirun -n 6 python test.py
import time
import torch
import torch.distributed as dist


def get_weights(A, Y, use_omp=False):
    # maximize OMP threads
    master = dist.get_rank() == 0
    if use_omp and master:
        ws = dist.get_world_size()
        th = torch.get_num_threads()
        torch.set_num_threads(ws*th)

    # actual calculation; only master
    if dist.get_rank() == 0:
        Q, R = torch.qr(A)
        W = (R.inverse()@Q.t()@Y)
        print(torch.get_num_threads())
    else:
        W = torch.zeros(A.shape[1], 1)
    dist.broadcast(W, 0)

    # reset OMP threads
    if use_omp and master:
        torch.set_num_threads(th)
    return W


def test(n=100000, m=300, s=10, use_omp=False):
    # ...
    # normal distributed code ...
    # ...
    A = torch.rand(n, m)
    _W = torch.rand(m, 1)
    Y = A @ _W
    W = get_weights(A, Y, use_omp=use_omp) # <- this
    res = W.allclose(_W, atol=1e-3)
    return res


def timeit(repeat=10, use_omp=False):
    t1 = time.time()
    for _ in range(repeat):
        test(use_omp=use_omp)
    t2 = time.time()
    return (t2-t1)/repeat


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dist.init_process_group('mpi')
    print(timeit(use_omp=False))   # -> 3.036880087852478
    print(timeit(use_omp=True))    # -> 1.3959508180618285
```

In the above example setting threads to 6 improved the speed by a factor of ~2. But when I try sth similar to this in my actual code (and on a much larger cluster) it became almost 2 times slower!

EDIT2: The essence of this question is that (on a single node with `n` cores) most of the calculation (70%) is optimal with MPI using `n` processes, the other part (30%) is optimal with `n` OMP threads. I was wondering about optimal utilization of the available cores in both parts.
Although the comments were very helpful, I guess there are no easy answers. In this particular case the mentioned region is a linear algebra problem and using `scalapack` is probably the best solution.
But the question stands for general cases.

Comment: That looks like a suboptimal solution since slaves are likely spin waiting for messages and it does requires you do **not** pin MPI tasks to cores (otherwise the threads on master will end up time sharing). A better approach is to make your program truly hybrid MPI+OpenMP and run one MPI task per node or socket, and use OpenMP to parallelize the chunk evaluation.

Comment: Yep, most OpenMP implementations will keep the threads spin-waiting for a new parallel region to be started.  Depending on the settings, this maybe be anywhere from a few (hundred) milliseconds to infinity. Plus, the OpenMP implementation will still use up resources (thread descriptors, memory mapping, etc.) that might get in the way in some cases.

Comment: You spawn `n` MPI processes, and you want to use `n` OMP threads. That means you have only one node, and effectively no distributed memory. Rewrite your application to use only OpenMP, because you dn't actually need MPI.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout this only a demonstration of the problem, in the actual code MPI is needed for the most of calculations. I only need faster torch.qr which is called on rank 0 and I am wondering if I can use the other cores as OMP threads.

Comment: If you are using MPI across multiple nodes, then you definitely cannot use "the other cores as OMP threads", because they do not share physical memory with the core on which MPI rank zero is running...

Answer (score 0):

I think from what I understood from your question is to launch the OpenMP threads for the computation and then shutdown the OpenMP implementation.  With your pseudo-code example, it would look like this:

```
a = g(mpi_rank, ... )          # process-specific matrix

A = mpi_gather(a, mpi_rank=0)  # gather all 

if mpi_rank == 0
    x = f(A)  ! do a parallel region in f()
    omp_pause_resource_all(omp_pause_hard)
else
    x = 0

mpi_bcast(x, mpi_rank=0)
```

See the functions [omp_pause_resource_all()](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu160.html#x203-2360003.6.2) and [omp_pause_resource()](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu159.html) of the OpenMP API specification.  They terminate most of the OpenMP implementation, such that only a very small part that should not affect performance will remain.

Note, the functions were introduced with OpenMP API version 5.0, so you will need a fairly new OpenMP compiler for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Arrange your MPI processes so that node 0 has only one process, and all other nodes have one process per core. Then process zero can easily launch an OpenMP (or otherwise threaded) shared-memory parallel section.